# Lambda calculus defining terms according to description

Tags: lambda-calculus

I'm working on a problem I stumbled across online.
The goal is to define terms for two use cases which are defined as follows:

lists are encoded as:

$ [N_1,N_2,...,N_k] ≜ λc.λn.c N_1 (c N_2 (...(c N_k n)...)) $

$ head [N, . . . ] → _\beta^* N \\ $

$ empty [ ] →_\beta^* true \\ $

$ empty [N, . . . ] →\beta^* false $

With a note that head[] can reduce to whatever I want. Any idea how to define such terms?

Comment: How do you encode lists?

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco edited the OT, with list encoding.

Comment: Note that in $\mathsf{head}(L),$ the argument $L$ is a function taking two arguments $c$ and $n$. What you need to do is to find $c$ and $n$ such that $Lcn=cN_1(cN_2(\cdots))=N_1.$ What should $c$ look like to take two arguments and return the first one?

Comment: How is the empty list encoded? Is it $\lambda c.\lambda n.n$?

Comment: Yes, it is $\lambda c.\lambda n.n

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Below, I will write definitions on the form $\mathsf{foo}(x_1,\ldots,x_n)=e$ as syntactic sugar for $\mathsf{foo}=\lambda x_1.\cdots.\lambda x_n.e$ and expressions on the form $\mathsf{foo}(e_1,\ldots,e_n)$ as syntactic sugar for $\mathsf{foo}\ e_1\ \ldots\ e_n$.

List constructors:

- $\mathsf{nil} = \lambda c.\lambda n.n$
- $\mathsf{cons}(x,l) = \lambda c.\lambda n.c\ x\ (l\ c\ n)$

By these we have for example
$$\begin{align}
\mathsf{cons}(N_1, \mathsf{nil}) 
&= \lambda c.\lambda n.c\ N_1\ (\mathsf{nil}\ c\ n)
\to_\beta \lambda c.\lambda n.c\ N_1\ n
\\
\mathsf{cons}(N_1, \mathsf{cons}(N_2, \mathsf{nil}))
&= \lambda c.\lambda n.c\ N_1\ (\mathsf{cons}(N_2, \mathsf{nil})\ c\ n)
\\
&= \lambda c.\lambda n.c\ N_1\ ((\lambda c'.\lambda n'.c'\ N_2\ n')\ c\ n)
\\
&\to_\beta \lambda c.\lambda n.c\ N_1\ (c\ N_2\ n)
\end{align}$$

To get the head of a list, we need to find some function $c_{\mathsf{head}}$ and some value $n$ such that $\mathsf{cons}(x,l)\ c_{\mathsf{head}}\ n$ reduces to $x$. But
$$
\mathsf{cons}(x,l)\ c_{\mathsf{head}}\ n 
= (\lambda c'.\lambda n'.c'\ x\ (l\ c'\ n'))\ c_{\mathsf{head}}\ n 
\to_\beta c_{\mathsf{head}}\ x\ (l\ c'\ n)
$$
so we see that we can just take $c_{\mathsf{head}} = \lambda x.\lambda r.x$ and the value of $n$ doesn't matter.
Therefore, we can take
$$
\mathsf{head}(l) = l\ (\lambda x.\lambda r.x)\ \mathsf{id}
$$
where $\mathsf{id}(x)=x$.

To check if a list is empty, we need to find some function $c_{\mathsf{empty}}$ and some value $n$ such that $\mathsf{nil}\ c_{\mathsf{empty}}\ n$ reduces to $\mathsf{true}$, while $\mathsf{cons}(x,l)\ c_{\mathsf{empty}}\ n$ reduces to $\mathsf{false}$. But
$$
\mathsf{nil}\ c_{\mathsf{empty}}\ n 
= (\lambda c'.\lambda n'.n')\ c_{\mathsf{empty}}\ n
\to_\beta n
$$
and
$$
\mathsf{cons}(x,l)\ c_{\mathsf{empty}}\ n 
= (\lambda c'.\lambda n'.c'\ x\ (l\ c'\ n'))\ c_{\mathsf{empty}}\ n
\to_\beta c_{\mathsf{empty}}\ x\ (l\ c_{\mathsf{empty}}\ n)
.
$$
Note that the result for $\mathsf{nil}$ equals $n$ so we can take $n=\mathsf{true}$, and the result for $\mathsf{cons}(x,l)$ is an application of $c_{\mathsf{empty}}$ so we can just let $c_{\mathsf{empty}}\ x\ r$ return $\mathsf{false}.$ We therefore define
$$
\mathsf{empty}(l) = l\ (\lambda x.\lambda r.\mathsf{false})\ \mathsf{true}
$$

---

Showing that $\mathsf{head}\ (\mathsf{cons}\ a\ l) \to_\beta^* a$:
$$\begin{align}
\mathsf{head}\ (\mathsf{cons}\ a\ l)
&= (\lambda l'.l'\ (\lambda x.\lambda r.x)\ \mathsf{id})\ (\mathsf{cons}\ a\ l) \\
&\to_\beta (\mathsf{cons}\ a\ l)\ (\lambda x.\lambda r.x)\ \mathsf{id} \\
&= ((\lambda x'.\lambda l'.\lambda c.\lambda n.c\ x'\ (l'\ c\ n))\ a\ l)\ (\lambda x.\lambda r.x)\ \mathsf{id} \\
&= (\lambda x'.\lambda l'.\lambda c.\lambda n.c\ x'\ (l'\ c\ n))\ a\ l\ (\lambda x.\lambda r.x)\ \mathsf{id} \\
&\to_\beta (\lambda l'.\lambda c.\lambda n.c\ a\ (l'\ c\ n))\ l\ (\lambda x.\lambda r.x)\ \mathsf{id} \\
&\to_\beta (\lambda c.\lambda n.c\ a\ (l\ c\ n))\ (\lambda x.\lambda r.x)\ \mathsf{id} \\
&\to_\beta (\lambda n.(\lambda x.\lambda r.x)\ a\ (l\ (\lambda x.\lambda r.x)\ n))\ \mathsf{id} \\
&\to_\beta (\lambda x.\lambda r.x)\ a\ (l\ (\lambda x.\lambda r.x)\ \mathsf{id})) \\
&\to_\beta (\lambda r.a)\ (l\ (\lambda x.\lambda r.x)\ \mathsf{id})) \\
&\to_\beta a \\
\end{align}$$

Comment: Hi, thank you for the answer, I'm a bit struggling to interpret the answer. In the head(l)=l (λx.λr.x) id, what is meant by the id? Is it possible to proof that it works by doing something like head([1,2,3] and then reducing it until we get the 1 out?

Comment: $\mathsf{id}=\lambda x.x$ But you can pass anything as second argument to $l$ in the definition of $\mathsf{head}$. The second argument isn't really used.

Comment: Try reducing $\mathsf{head}([1,2,3])$ yourself. It's easy, and it will only require a few steps.

Comment: So can we just omit the ID?

Comment: Not omit; $l$ needs two arguments. But you can replace it with whatever you want.

Comment: First step is correct. The rest is incorrect.

Comment: It's an illegal reduction. You can not reduce $(\lambda n.f\ m\ x\ y\ z)\ a$ to $m\ (x\ y\ z)\ a$.

Comment: What $\lambda$-term do you think that you have applied to what argument when doing your reduction?

Comment: The $\lambda n$ term ends just before $\mathsf{id},$ i.e. you have $(\lambda n.\mathit{something})\ \mathsf{id}$ which $\beta$-reduces to $\mathit{something}[n:=\mathsf{id}]$.

Comment: Apply $(\lambda x.\lambda r.x)$ on $3$.

Comment: $(\lambda r.3)\ ((\lambda x.\lambda r.x)\ 2\ ((\lambda x.\lambda r.x)\ 1\ \mathsf{id}))$

Comment: Your parentheses don't match, but after adding the missing ones the calculation looks okay. Note that you could directly have reduced $(\lambda r.3)\ (\ldots)$ to $3$ without first reducing $(\ldots)$. But there are different [reduction strategies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda_calculus#Reduction_strategies).

Comment: In my post I have added a reduction of $\mathsf{head}\ (\mathsf{cons}\ a\ l)$ to $a$. There I have used *normal order* reduction.

Comment: I've found another expression which reduces as well. How is this: $λl.l(λab.a)(any expression)$ different to the solution you've provided in the answer for head ?

Comment: @gaming4mining. It's practically the same. The only thing that might differ is the part $(anyexpression)$ that anyway doesn't matter.